# devstack - edit nova.conf file using local.conf file

Tags: python, shell, openstack

I am using Devstack in my development environment.

For adding some configuration entries in nova.conf file, we can use the code as follows:

```
[[post-config|$NOVA_CONF]]
[DEFAULT]
notification_driver=messagingv2
notification_topics=notifications,trackinstance
```

Now consider such entry is existing in nova.conf file.

I need to edit the same now.

Is there any default way available with devstack like post-config.

Someone let me know the way for the same.

Answer (score 1):

I can be able to find the solution for the same.

Same post-config can be used for the same.

When field exists already , It is simply update the field instead adding it.